# VB6 Data type for coordinates (rectangle) that can be used a parameter Data Type

Tags: vb6

I frequently find I want to pass coordinates to a Sub() but you can't Pass a User Defined Type.

Is there any built in type?
For example, something like Line.

I'm trying to avoid dependencies as this is shrinkwrap software.

Comment: you can pass a class, though, right?

Comment: There's no built-in type as far as I can remember... You might have to define your own.

Comment: ... well there is a [Rect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240516(v=vs.60).aspx) object but you'll have to reference the MSChart control. I think you're better off defining your own.

Comment: Passing a UDT is usually possible, where/how are you declaring it and where/how is the Sub declared? What error do you encounter when trying to pass it to the Sub?

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely pass a user-defined type.  You just need to make sure you use the ByRef keyword.

```
Sub ExampleSub(ByRef Rect As Recatangle)
End Sub
```

And of course you will have to define the UDT:

```
Public Type Rectangle
   Left As Long   
   Top As Long
   Width As Long
   Height As Long
End Type
```